# jquery ajax not catch the data back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this jquery ajax script

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "register.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&confirm_password=" + confirm_password + "&captcha=" + captcha,
    success: function(data){
    if(data == "Success"){
      $("#tombol_submit").remove();
      $("#register_sukses").fadeIn(500);
    }else{
      $("#register_gagal").html(data).fadeIn(500);
      $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled").attr("value", "Submit");
    }
}
```

in the register.php, once the data successfully added to database, it will echo the "Success" word, the word Success is appear in the form page, but the button (tombol_submit) not removed, otherwise it back into Submit button (just like in 'else' statement). How to remove the button, so the client cannot click the submit button again?

here's the register.php script

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "config/koneksi.php";

    if(!empty($_POST['captcha'])){
         if($_POST['captcha'] == $_SESSION['hasil']){
             $fullname = $_POST['name'];
             $email = $_POST['email'];
             $password = md5($_POST['password']);

             $queryform = "INSERT INTO register (fullname,email,pass) 
                    VALUES('$fullname','$email','$password')";
             if ($hasilform = mysqli_query($konek2, $queryform)) {
                 echo "Success";
             } else {
                 echo "Failed";
             }
         } else {
             echo "The captcha code is wrong";
         }
     } else {
         echo "The captcha cannot be empty";
     }
?>
```

Comment: try to console.log(data); then paste the result here

Comment: please make sure you are trying with correct id. otherwise please post HTML too.

Comment: `if(data == 'Success'){` Remember case-sensitivity as well....

Comment: Hi @JayBryanCañas, there's nothing in the console.log

Comment: @YupiterAryo so your code doesn't return any results. Problem is behind your php code. Please add it to the post too.

Comment: it means you're not returning the "Success" message from your php. can you update your question with the php code?

Comment: what is the last thing your php script did after inserting all the Data to the DB? Did it end with something like `echo "Success";` or `echo "Failure";`?

Comment: I have update my post @JayBryanCañas and you are right Poiz

Comment: Is that wrong @Poiz?

Answer (score 2):

Normally `$().remove()` will work.

If you are asking why this `if...else...` doesn't work and always goes to `else`, please check the response from your backend to make sure the response is only a "Success" string.

Comment: I try to remove the else statement, but it is just same, the button not removed

Comment: @YupiterAryo Like i said, you should check you PHP code to make sure that response is exactly "Success". Remove the else statement will do nothing help.

Comment: it is success Ryan Hu, the data stored in the database

Comment: @YupiterAryo Try ```console.log(data);``` to see what your PHP code has returned.

Comment: it says Success

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$("#tombol_submit").css("display","none");
```

Comment: if remove is not working, how this will work ??? can you please explain

Comment: Please check your response string and make condition according to it

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$("#tombol_submit").hide();
```

Comment: Again same question to you... how this will work, if remove is not working??

Comment: i doubt it is not even going in Success  condition

Comment: it is Success @Chetan, the data stored in mysql database

Comment: Just to check issue lie withing response text or not , do one thing remove your Success  condition and remove element and check element is removing or not...

Comment: @YupiterAryo Like this -  success: function(data){
      $("#tombol_submit").remove();
    
    }

Comment: the button removed @Chetan, so where's the problem?

Comment: @YupiterAryo - refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507366/return-a-json-object-using-php-json-encode-mysql-to-pass-to-jquery-function

Answer (score 0):

i think 
id "tombol_submit" is not exit

Check console for error,

then based on error you can fix the problem.